# App on Facebook mobile gives me 4oh4 / 404

Tags: facebook, mobile, http-status-code-404

we have created a Facebook app, but when opening this on a mobile (via Web or iPhone) the page results in a 4oh4 error. I have setup a Mobile Web URL but still (after 1 hour wait) gives a 404.

Do I need to make specific changes on my app?

Please help.

Comment: Without knowing your app settings, having you confirm it's not in Sandbox mode, and how you're trying to access the app, we can't help you

Comment: True :-)

It happens if people go to this link (shared via posts, or via tabbpage link or somehow) https://www.facebook.com/TheHagueFestivals/app_411468148868842
you will be redirected to https://m.facebook.com/4oh4.php?id=188324859204&_rdr

If you go to the app directly theres no 404

Comment: That's a link to a page tab, pages on mobile don't have tabs , so i think this is expected; when you say 'go to the app directly' - do you  mean via apps.facebook.com/[something]?

Comment: is there any reason not to use the link in the format apps.facebook/something rather than use a redirector?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected as @Igy stated.  You will need to have a handler to support redirecting mobile users to your apps.facebook.com/ or you can redirect them out of Facebook to your own URL if you are going to try and link to your page directly with an app embedded as a tab.

i.e. point link to http://yoursite.com/redirector

- **is mobile** goes to http://yoursite.com/myapp or http://apps.facebook.com/
- **non mobile** goes to http://facebook.com//app_

Some things to note:

1. You won't get any page specific data back from facebook on your page (i.e. Liked or Not Liked).
2. Based on #1 you won't be able to restrict the non-liking app users from a page.

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything under the sun to get Facebook to redirect to a mobile web URL, here is what I needed to do in order to get the redirection working:

1. Make sure the Facebook application is a canvas application. This gives you the ability to give the application a namespace.
2. Give your application a namespace so that you can access it through https://apps.facebook.com/NAMESPACE. From here, Facebook will do the detection for you, and if needed, redirect your users to your specified mobile URL.
3. Make sure your app is NOT in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is in Sandbox Mode, Facebook won't redirect you to the mobile version you have specified in your app settings.

Facebook does the redirecting for you, you don't have to. Although their version of what "mobile" is and what you deem "mobile" might be different.